# How do I get column data from list webpart using javascript based on the webparts selected item

Tags: javascript, web-part, list-view, column, multi-select

Scenario:

I am trying to create a group mailto function for one of my SharePoint pages. The idea is that the user can select the groups they wish to bulk e-mail within our organisation. They click a button and this gathers the e-mails before opening the default e-mail application.

The mailto list (LU_Mailto) has the fields [Title] and [Mailto]. [Mailto] contains a string of e-mail addresses separated by semi colons (;). For example;

"Head of School", "jo.bloggs@auniversity.co.uk; a.nother@auniversity.co.uk"

I have placed the list as a WebPart on a page;

[image: List WebPart]

I have created JS code that gets the list items that have been selected when the E-mail Selected button is pressed.

```
function clickMethod_Mailto() {

   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //selected list Id
   var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx); //selected Items Ids
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
   var mySeletedItems = '';
   var mailto = '';
   var titles = '';

   var i;

   for (i in items)
   {

      row = list.getItemById(items[i].id);
      mySeletedItems += '|' + items[i].id; // this proves the selected IDs are being found

      titles = titles + row.get_item('Title'); // this line is not working  
//      titles = titles + row.get_item('Name'); // this line is not working 
//      mailto = mailto + row.get_item('Mailto'); // this line is not working   
   }

alert (mySeletedItems, titles, mailto);

}
```

If I comment out the "titles = titles + row.get_item('Title');" the function correctly returns a list of the selected item IDs. The [row] variable appears to be picking up an object but I am unable to get any column data from it. I am unsure whether I am referencing the column data correctly.

I have also tried "titles = titles + row.get_item('Name');" since the Title column was re-named. However, I have checked the column name and it is still Title internally and Name is just an alias.

If I can demonstrate that I can pull the Name of selected items in the WebPart then I can move onto the Mailto field. However, I am not sure if it has to be visible in the WebPart to be referenced?

Application: This is using SharePoint 2013

Any help and guidance gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found/worked out a solution using .executeQueryAsync and CAML query [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241677/what-kind-of-objects-can-i-load-for-use-by-executequeryasync/241779#241779)